# how to split the string wtih brackets?

Tags: python

I'd like to splitt the below string into something like this
`'180-240','0-100','100-200','0-110','200-240','0-120'`

```
a='(180-240,0-100),(100-200,0-110),(200-240,0-120)'
a
'(180-240,0-100),(100-200,0-110),(200-240,0-120)'
```

After the below split, it is still one element of string, I am expecting to get a lsit with 3 tuples of

```
['(180-240,0-100','100-200,0-110','200-240,0-120)']
```

However I got below a list with only one string. Not sure where is the problem? Thanks

```
b=a.split('(,)')
b
['(180-240,0-100),(100-200,0-110),(200-240,0-120)']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many possible solutions, use `re`:

```
import re

a = "(180-240,0-100),(100-200,0-110),(200-240,0-120)"

print(re.findall(r"[^)(,]+", a))
```

Prints:

```
['180-240', '0-100', '100-200', '0-110', '200-240', '0-120']
```

Comment: This solution is fine, but `re` is overkill here. Simply using `.strip('()')` should do the job.

Comment: @Jules Can you write this as an answer? I'll upvote it...